# Получить ID потока в переменную

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность, posix

Как извлечь ID потока из pthread_self() в целочисленную переменную? То есть что-то типа такого:

```
int a=pthread_self();
```

Или если этого сделать нельзя, то как вывести на экран ID потока при помощи cout. В стиле C это получается:

```
printf("thread id = %d\n", pthread_self());
```

а строка

```
cout<<pthread_self();
```

даёт ошибку

Comment: какую ошибку ? Опишите подробнее. Так же попробуйте static_cast<int>(pthread_self())

Comment: `syscall(SYS_gettid)`

Comment: `typedef unsigned long int pthread_t;` так что кастом в этот тип перед выводом.

Comment: "В стиле C это получается..." Нет, не получается. Уже давно нет гарантии того, что `pthread_t` имеет арифметический тип. Пытаться печатать его таким образом бесполезно.

Answer (score 2):

Тип ID потока свободен и может быть исполнен в любом исполнении разными компиляторами. Можно нарисовать как список байтов так :

```
// g++ -Wall -Wpedantic showthrid.cpp
# include <iostream>
typedef
union {
  volatile pthread_t tid;
  volatile uint8_t bid [sizeof(pthread_t)];
  }
uid ;

int main(){
    uid u ;
    u.tid = pthread_self();
    std::cout<<"pthread_self = "<<std::hex;
    for(int i=sizeof(pthread_t);i;){
        -- i ;
        std::cout<<((unsigned int )u.bid[i])<<".";
        }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<" = "<<((size_t)u.tid)<<std::endl; }

$ ./a.out 
pthread_self = 0.0.7f.3b.21.d0.4d.80.
 = 7f3b21d04d80
```

И если вы найдёте численный тип с нужным размером, то на этот тип и кидайте значение. У меня размер 8 байт. То есть можно впихнуть в **size_t**.

Comment: Чтение неактивного поля `bid` является неопределенным поведением.

Comment: @VTT `volatile` обычно спасает от умных компиляторов. Так что такой код будет пахать 99%.

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_self` возвращает дескриптор потока, не особо пригодный для печати и чтения. Получить числовой идентификатор потока можно так:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long id;
    errno = 0;
    id = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    if(0 != errno)
    {
        perror("syscall(SYS_gettid) failed");
        abort();
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "thread id %li", id);
    return 0;
}
```